# Rotary dialer like animation not working exactly

Tags: iphone, gps

I am using MHRotaryKnob to make Rotary dial like animation. I am using it for making old telephone dial pad.[image]. At present it is just showing animation when i dial the pad it just come back with animation. even the first circle from lower not even getting touch detected and touch is working there also where there is no circle to dial. Below i am posting the code i am using.

```
 - (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];

if (self.interactionStyle == MHRotaryKnobInteractionStyleRotating)
{
    // If the touch is too close to the center, we can't calculate a decent
    // angle and the knob becomes too jumpy.
    if ([self squaredDistanceToCenter:point] < MinDistanceSquared)
        return NO;

    // Calculate starting angle between touch and center of control.
    _angle = [self angleBetweenCenterAndPoint:point];
}
else
{
    _touchOrigin = point;
    _angle = [self angleForValue:self.value];
}

self.highlighted = YES;
[self showHighlighedKnobImage];
_canReset = NO;

return YES;
}

- (BOOL)handleTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
if (touch.tapCount > 1 && self.resetsToDefault && _canReset)
{
    [self setValue:self.defaultValue animated:YES];
    return NO;
}

CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];

if (self.interactionStyle == MHRotaryKnobInteractionStyleRotating)
{
    if ([self squaredDistanceToCenter:point] < MinDistanceSquared)
        return NO;

    // Calculate how much the angle has changed since the last event.
    float newAngle = [self angleBetweenCenterAndPoint:point];
    float delta = newAngle - _angle;
    _angle = newAngle;

    // We don't want the knob to jump from minimum to maximum or vice versa
    // so disallow huge changes.
    if (fabsf(delta) > 45.0f)
        return NO;

    self.value += (self.maximumValue - self.minimumValue) * delta / (MaxAngle*2.0f);

    // Note that the above is equivalent to:
    //self.value += [self valueForAngle:newAngle] - [self valueForAngle:angle];
}
else
{
    self.value = [self valueForPosition:point];
}

return YES;
}

- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if ([self handleTouch:touch] && self.continuous)
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

return YES;
}

- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
self.highlighted = NO;
[self showNormalKnobImage];

// You can only reset the knob's position if you immediately stop dragging
// the knob after double-tapping it, i.e. when tracking ends.
_canReset = YES;

[self handleTouch:touch];
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self setValue:self.defaultValue animated:YES];


}
```

I am trying to achieve that which circle is selected to dial that can be detected and only circles can be used to dial not outside the circles. Thanks in advance, any sort of help is appreciated.